# Convert JSON date string to Python datetime

Tags: python, json, datetime, date, iso

When translating dates to JSON, javascript is saving dates in this format:

```
2012-05-29T19:30:03.283Z
```

However, I am not sure how to get this into a python datetime object. I've tried these:

```
# Throws an error because the 'Z' isn't accounted for:
datetime.datetime.strptime(obj[key], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')

# Throws an error because '%Z' doesn't know what to do with the 'Z'
#  at the end of the string
datetime.datetime.strptime(obj[key], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z')
```

I believe that javascript is saving the string in official ISO format, so it seems that there should be a way to get python's `datetime.strptime()` to read it?

Comment: Remove the % in front of the "Z", I think that should work.

Comment: Doesn't that remove the information that 'Z' conveys?

Comment: @ChrisDutrow Z is a character to ignore in the string

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try the following format:

```
%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ
```

For example:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2012-05-29T19:30:03.283Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 29, 19, 30, 3, 283000)
```

The `Z` in the date just means that it should be interpreted as a UTC time, so ignoring it won't cause any loss of information.  You can find this information here: http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: How would you get rid of the time part of the date? When trying with just `%Y-%m-%d` or `%Y-%m-%dT` it doesn't seem to work.  Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out using `datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ').strftime("%m/%d/%y")`

Answer (score 14):

To provide an alternative, if you don't mind installing the [`python-dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/) package, you can use [`dateutil.parser.parse`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse). Be advised that the format of the input is guessed by `parse`; an invalid input can still be interpreted, correctly or otherwise. Guessing the format will however be significantly slower than specifying it explicitly.

#### Without timezone

If you would rather not have the time zone set, which is perfectly fine if you represent all times internally as UTC only, use:

```
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('2012-05-29T19:30:03.283Z', ignoretz=True)
datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 29, 19, 30, 3, 283000)
```

#### With timezone

Note that unlike `datetime.datetime.strptime`, this default call to `parse` automatically preserves the UTC time zone.

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('2012-05-29T19:30:03.283Z')
datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 29, 19, 30, 3, 283000, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

If a test assertion for equality needs to be made, the expected object can be constructed as:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 29, 19, 30, 3, 283000, tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzutc())
```

Comment: Preserving the time zone is important.  I prefer your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import datetime

# Assuming you have a string in the format
date_string = "2012-05-29T19:30:03.283Z"

# You can build a datetime object with
date_object = datetime.fromisoformat(date_string)
```