# How to convert JSON date & time to Python datetime?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, datetime, timezone

I get the date and time as string like `2014-05-18T12:19:24+04:00`

I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805589/converting-json-date-string-to-python-datetime) explaining how to handle dates in UTC timezone (`2012-05-29T19:30:03.283Z`)

What should I do with `+04:00` in my case (if I want to store time in UTC timezone in Python)?

**Upd**. I've tried to parse it like below:

```
dt = '2014-05-19T14:48:50+04:00'
plus_position = dt.find('+') # remove column in the timezone part
colon_pos = dt.find(':', plus_position)
dt = dt[:colon_pos] + dt[colon_pos+1:]
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z') # '2014-05-19T14:48:50+0400'
```

But it fails - `'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'`

Comment: `datetime.isoformat` produces a timezone with a colon. `%z` expects a timezone without a colon. Hahaha. Ha. =(

Answer (score 3):

Using [`dateutil`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil):

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('2014-05-18T12:19:24+04:00')
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 18, 12, 19, 24, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 14400))
```

Comment: Thanks, but can I do the same without `dateutil`? It requires `six` to be installed... I don't like to use many 3rd party modules with GAE environment.