# Python date format from mongodb date

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm getting a date from mongodb like `2015-07-09T22:04:51.974Z`, I want to format this string in Python to something like "Wed, July 7, 2015"

Does python have any libraries for working with this type of date and formatting?  I can't seem to find anything specific to this.

Comment: `datetime`. Especially `strftime` and `strptime`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805589/converting-json-date-string-to-python-datetime