# normalizing JSON datestrings to UTC python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, datetime

I have an important test that says "Calculate users that logged in during the month of April normalized to the UTC timezone."

Items look as such:

```
[ {u'email': u' ybartoletti@littel.biz',
  u'login_date': u'2014-05-08T22:30:57-04:00'},
 {u'email': u'woodie.crooks@kozey.com',
  u'login_date': u'2014-04-25T13:27:48-08:00'},
]
```

It seems to me that an item like `2014-04-13T17:12:20-04:00` means "April 13th, 2014, at 5:12:20 pm, 4 hours behind UTC". Then I just use strptime to convert to datetime ([Converting JSON date string to python datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805589/converting-json-date-string-to-python-datetime)), and subtract a timedelta of however many hours I get from a regex that grabs the end of string? I feel this way because some have a + at the end instead of -, like `2014-05-07T00:30:06+07:00`

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably best to use the [`dateutil.parser.parse`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/2.5.0) and [`pytz`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz) packages for this purpose. This will allow you to parse a string and convert it to a datetime object with UTC timezone:

```
>>> s = '2014-05-08T22:30:57-04:00'
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> import pytz
>>> pytz.UTC.normalize(dateutil.parser.parse(s))
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 9, 2, 30, 57, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Comment: Is there a major difference between `pytz.UTC.normalize(t)` and `t.astimezone(pytz.UTZ)` as I had in my (now deleted) answer?

Comment: @mgilson: in my understanding not for UTC but it could make a difference for other timezones. In the `pytz` documentation I also see the following being used: `au_dt = au_tz.normalize(utc_dt.astimezone(au_tz))` - I'm not sure why it is done that way.

Comment: wow, as you were answering I just wasted 15 mins and 10 lines of code lol. very nice, let me test

Comment: that was so beautiful. I haven't seen that parser before simeon

Comment: This bug report also seems to be related:  https://answers.launchpad.net/pytz/+question/249229

Comment: Hmmm ... I was under the same impression as you, but (unless I'm reading it incorrectly) the source seems to imply that astimezone should be used for conversions (even though normalize also works)... I'm still trying to wrap my head around this one though. I have timezones ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [arrow](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/) to easily parse date with time zone.

```
>>>import arrow
>>> a = arrow.get('2014-05-08T22:30:57-04:00').to('utc')
>>> a
<Arrow [2014-05-09T02:30:57+00:00]>
```

Get a datetime object or timestamp:

```
>>> a.datetime
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 9, 2, 30, 57, tzinfo=tzutc())
>>> a.naive
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 9, 2, 30, 57)
>>> a.timestamp
1399602657
```

Comment: is that datetype specific to arrow? does arrow have a convert func to python?

Comment: @codyc4321 Arrow datetype specific for module, but you can easily get datetime object if you need

Answer (score 1):

The following solution should be faster and avoids importing external libraries. The downside is that it will only work if the date strings are all *guaranteed* to have the specified format. If that's not the case, then I would prefer Simeon's solution, which lets `dateutil.parser.parse()` take care of any inconsistencies.

```
import datetime as dt

def parse_date(datestr):
    diff = dt.timedelta(hours=int(datestr[20:22]), minutes=int(datestr[23:]))
    if datestr[19] == '-':
        return dt.datetime.strptime(datestr[:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') - diff
    return dt.datetime.strptime(datestr[:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') + diff
```

Comment: it seems faster and more native but it's not guaranteed in this case, I didn't write the api