# How to change time zone of a variable with time

Tags: python, datetime, time, timezone

I have a variable that stores a date taken from a JSON file:
[image]

I have to change the time zone to what is currently in Thailand. Simply put, add 6 hours to the current time with a possible change of date. 
How can I easily change the time zone? I tried to use **datetime** library for this, but it did not bring any results.

Comment: Please paste the time instead of putting an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert it to a `datetime` object and then add the offset hours using `timedelta`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

d = datetime.fromisoformat("2019-12-18T15:20:58.950911+01:00")
print(d)
d2 = d.astimezone(timezone(timedelta(hours=6)))
print(d2)
```

Output:

```
2019-12-18 15:20:58.950911+01:00
2019-12-18 20:20:58.950911+06:00
```

**UPDATE:** If using python < 3.7, `fromisoformat` isn't avaiable, so you should use `strptime` instead, see e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10805633/2495746

Comment: `datetime.fromisoformat` only works for python >= 3.7